# IBOutlet not connecting in Interface Builder- Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, xcode4.2

I have read other questions here, but they seem to be for Xcode 3.2 or earlier, but nothing for 4.2. :(

I started a simple project and was wanting to connect the File Owner's Outlets within my xib.  The bummer is that my IBOutlet's from my ViewController.h aren't coming over.

I don't have a reputation of 10 or above, so [here is a screenshot of my File's Owner not showing my IBOutlets](http://www.cssburst.com/Websites/homeboy/images/StackOverflow/Files%20Owner.png).

Here is my ViewController.h code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController { 
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtName; 
    IBOutlet UILabel *lblMessage;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *txtName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *lblMessage;

- (IBAction)doSomething;

@end
```

Here is my ViewController.m code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize txtName;
@synthesize lblMessage;

- (IBAction) doSomething
{
    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@",txtName.text];
    [lblMessage setText:msg];
}

@end
```

I am new to Objective-C and Xcode, so I could have made a mistake, but I've followed many tutorials and I can never get my IBOutlets to show.  I have gone as far as to delete Xcode 4.2 and re-installed to try and fix this issue.  Here is a [screenshot of my Xcode Version 4.2, Build 4D199 info](http://www.cssburst.com/Websites/homeboy/images/StackOverflow/xcode.png).

Anyone else run into this issue? Thanks anyone who can point out any mistakes I have made.  Please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you create your IBAction, in the .h file, there will be a connection indicator to the left of it. When it isn't connected it shows a empty circle.

Press and hold this and drag it to the item you want to connect it to. I usually open up the XIB in a new window by double clicking it.

[image: Connect the IBAction to your button by dragging from the the .h file]

---

If it wont connect you must set the `File's Owner` in the XIB file. Select `File's Owner` in the Placeholders panel. Move over to the Utilities panel and make sure the `Custom class`, in  `Identity Inspector`, is set to what ever your viewcontroller is named.

[image: Set files owner]

I Hope this will help you.

Cheers!

Comment: The second part of this did the trick.  I guess I assumed it was set by default.  I really appreciate the help and the screenshots!

Comment: I tried almost everything, but your 1st trick of opening a new window and then dragging it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Try to reassign your file owner class reference in xib file.

Then attach all your IBOutlet connections.

Hope this might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the Files Owner is set to "ViewController". Check the following link:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/InterfaceBuilder/InterfaceBuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

Two things need to be added, before Xcode will allow creation of IBOutlet for the text field from the Storyboard:

1. Assign the underlying ViewController as the delegate to the UITextField
2. Add the  to the @interface declaration in the ViewController.h file:

   @interface ViewController : UIViewController<**UITextFieldDelegate**>

Until both of these are completed, you can Ctrl-click and drag from the Storyboard to the .h file, but no IBOutlet connection will be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally figured out the issue, hope this helps anyone else currently having the same problem. 
It had nothing to do with the xib's file owner setting.  What my issue was that I had the xib file in a different directory than the source files, thus it wasn't able to connect the outlets. Once I moved the files to the same directory, everything worked. FYI, I moved everything to the top directory.  Not sure sub directories will work...

To move the files, be sure to update xcode to point to the new locations.